# SQL: Getting the latest date using Max() while using group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling to get the correct result with this query:

```
select max(kts.my_date),  kts.name
join ktt on ktt.someId = kts.someOtherId
where ktt.someId = 'example' 
group by kts.name;
```

I have two (possibly stupid) questions:

1. Will this max() take time into account? I know that order by does if the dates are the same.  Does max do the same?
2. This is connected to my previous question,  but when I run the query above, if the dates are same,  it orders it by the name. I want the latest date at the top.  Do I need to put an order by clause for the date in?  If so,  using Max is pointless,  right?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Assuming my_date is a date field, then yes, it will take time into account.  You do need an order by if you want it to sort by date.  All the max does it take the max date **for each name**.  If you can provide actual data, it may add some context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it may be easier if I told you what I am trying to do: I'm trying to get latest date from all the rows that matches the where clause,  and get the accompanying  name in that row as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes,

`--2
select max(kts.my_date) over (partition by kts.name) as maxdate,  kts.name
from -- chose your table
join ktt on ktt.someId = kts.someOtherId
where ktt.someId = 'example' 
order by --chose here your column`

give this a try